# how to use dolly.js over already define html table for functionality of excel like drag and copy the cell of table

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

see this js fiddle[http://jsfiddle.net/pUAXd/17/]
i am creating my table in html body and want to use drag and copy functionality of dooly.js over my table like the 2nd table..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to grab the data from the table before the rederizartion and then use this data to create the table with dolly.js

```
tableController.element = $("table");
tableController.data = [];
tableController.element.find('tr').each(function(i, line) {
    var lineData = [];
    $(line).find('td').each(function(j, cell) {
        lineData.push($(cell).html());
    });
    tableController.data.push(lineData);
});
tableController.render();
```

I've updated the fiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/pUAXd/66/

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks @rafael..by d way.i had alrdy find solution by my slef..and this above jsfiddle is mine only....:) thanks for contributing