# The Dolly.js goes unresponsive if I have 40+ rows with 50 columns. Any solution?

Tags: jquery, excel

[how to use dolly.js over already define html table for functionality of excel like drag and copy the cell of table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21902079/how-to-use-dolly-js-over-already-define-html-table-for-functionality-of-excel-li)

This question has the details about using dolly.js. I need to use it with a large table of 40+ rows with 50 columns. This goes unresponsive with this no. of cells. Any solution?

Comment: I get unresponsiveness when using Chromium but it loads when using Firefox, though it takes long time.